# How to remove rows where there is a zero or NA in the in specific two columns using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns. I am interested in removing any 0 or NA from the two columns. Please see the sample below.

```
Input <- data.frame(DM = LETTERS[1:8], JM = LETTERS[19:26], CY = c(1,2,0,NA,5,34,0,NA), LY = c(2,4,NA,NA,-5,6,0,0))

DM  JM  CY  LY
A    S  1    2
B    T  2    4
C    U  0    NA
D    V  NA   NA
E    W  5    -5
F    X  34   6
G    Y  0    0
H    Z  NA   0
```

I tried following:

```
Output<-Input[rowSums(Input[c("CY", "LY")], na.rm = TRUE) != 0, ]
```

Based on the code I received following output.

```
DM  JM  CY  LY
A    S  1    2
B    T  2    4
F    X  34   6
```

I would like to get the output even if the sum is 0. Desired output:

```
DM  JM  CY  LY
A    S  1    2
B    T  2    4
E    W  5    -5
F    X  34   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either convert the zeros to NA or NA to 0s and then use `rowSums` on a logical matrix and negate the logical vector to subset the rows

```
Input[!!rowSums(replace(Input[c("CY", "LY")],
          is.na(Input[c("CY", "LY")]), 0) != 0),]
#   DM JM CY LY
#1  A  S  1  2
#2  B  T  2  4
#5  E  W  5 -5
#6  F  X 34  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two step way.

```
Input <- na.omit(Input)
Input[rowSums(Input[3:4] == 0) == 0, ]
#  DM JM CY LY
#1  A  S  1  2
#2  B  T  2  4
#5  E  W  5 -5
#6  F  X 34  6
```

And a one-liner.

```
Input[rowSums(Input[3:4] == 0 | is.na(Input[3:4])) == 0, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to remove any NAs or zeros:

```
Input[Reduce(`&`, lapply(Input, function(x) x != 0 & !is.na(x))),]
#>   DM JM CY LY
#> 1  A  S  1  2
#> 2  B  T  2  4
#> 5  E  W  5 -5
#> 6  F  X 34  6
```